# Not getting right Output

Tags: java

I have created a program to delete a character from a string using a scanner class and it will give an output without that alphabet. e.g.

Input: " THIS IS INDIA"

Input(character to delete): I

Output: THS S NDA

I haven't tried anything extra.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringDel
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String S,str;
        int l,i,ch,chr,s2;
        s2=0;
        System.out.println("Enter a character");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the character you want to delete");
        chr = sc.next().charAt(0);
        l = str.length();
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            if(ch!=chr)
              s2= s2 + ch;
        }
        System.out.println("Output:" +s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question Aftab , please see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

```
int l,i,ch,chr,s2;
```

This line declares all of these variables as `int`s.

You don't want them all to be `int`: an `int` contains a number (a whole number). But things like `s2` obviously shouldn't be numbers, if you want its final value to be `THS S NDA`.

`ch` and `chr` should be `char`s, `s2` should be a `String`:

```
int l, i;
char ch, chr;
String s2;
```

and the initial value you assign to `s2` has to be a `String`:

```
s2 = "";
```

Also: declare variables where you actually first need them, for example:

```
    char chr = sc.next().charAt(0);
    int l = str.length();
    String s2 = "";
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(ch!=chr) {
          s2 = s2 + ch;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your variables are of the wrong types:

```
int l,i;
char ch,chr;
String s2="";
```

and remove 
    s2=0;

by this change your code will work.

addittionally Java String has the function replaceAll that you can use it to do it this way:

```
s2 = str.replaceAll(chr+"", "");
```

as a last comment you have an unused variable in your code in the line:

```
String S,str;
```

the variable S you are not using it in your code ever after so its a good practice to get rid of it, also the names of the variable is a good practice to have them start with lowercase.